# Как опубликовать сайт на Django?

Tags: маршрутизатор, порт

Первый раз просто это делаю. Купил статический IP у провайдера, запустил тестовый проект джанго, по 2ip проверяю порт 8000, который открыл и в брэндмауэре и в роутере, сайт пишет, что порт открыт но почему-то сайт не грузится по внешнему ip

Comment: Перенаправь через роутер порт 80 и 443 на свой локальный статический IP компьютера который выдает модем (192.168.1.X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело оказалось в Django, нужно было явно указывать при старте: python manage.py runserver 192.168.100.12:80 (локальный ip моего компа) или вообще 0.0.0.0:80 более универсальный способ

Answer (score 1):

Половина роутеров не может разобрать доступ к внешнему ip адресу через внутреннюю сеть.

Нужно добавить правило

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

В интернете это называют hairpin nat.

Как это сделать зависит от производителя ПО роутера

Comment: мне кажется дело не в этом, уже пробовал вообще отключать nat и брэндмауэр на роутере

Comment: @СашаБезгин дело в этом или в фаере винды. Не убрать а добавить правило нужно